# mitmproxy: reject content-type via script

Tags: http-headers, content-type, mitmproxy

I would like to reject all images, videos and sounds when browsing any domain but I cant seem to get it working. For rejecting images I have this script...
Command: `mitmdump -s reject.py`

```
from mitmproxy import http


def request(flow):
    if flow.request.headers.get("content-type") == "image/*":
        flow.response = http.Response.make(404, b"Rejected")
```

mitmdump runs on a linux machine while I am browsing via firefox on a windows machine with firefox setup to use proxy as linux-ip:8080; the setup works.

I tried cnn.com but I can still see images. I started learning mitmproxy only a day ago so I do not understand the scripting feature completely.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit (8/15/23): Solved with a "response(flow)"

```
from mitmproxy import http

def response(flow):
    if flow.response.status_code not in [101, 201, 204, 302, 301, 304]: # trying to avoid 'None' type in content.split
        my_content = flow.response.headers.get("content-type")
        if my_content:
            iana_header = my_content.split('/', 2)
            if iana_header[0] in ("audio", "example", "font", "image", "message", "model", "video"):
                flow.response = http.Response.make(404, b"Rejected")
            elif iana_header[0] == 'application':
                print(iana_header[1])
                # [wordperfect5.1] - this brings back memories
                if iana_header[1] not in ["dns", "gzip", "http", "javascript", "json", "pdf", "rtf",
                                          "xhtml+xml", "xml", "xml-dtd", "xml-external-parsed-entity",
                                          "xml-patch+xml", "zip"]:
                    flow.response = http.Response.make(404, b"Rejected")
```

How do I change this so that a http **request** is blocked, without checking for every extension (jpg/pdf/avi/mp4/doc etc. etc. etc.) ?